# Azure Website SSL

Tags: php, azure, azure-web-app-service

I not sure why i'm getting this error after i migrated my wordpress to Azure Websites. Previously the site working perfectly without any issue. I tried to install SSL (from comodo) to Azure Websites, top up SSL from cloudflare but it still not working.

```
MailChimp API Response :  SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Some online user said need to define the php.ini, but we have no access over the file hence i'm adding the following line to wp-config.php

```
ini_set('curl.cainfo', "cacert.pem");
```

the file located at same directory as wp-config. but it's still not working. please advice. 
(I'm using custom domain)

Comment: That won't change the setting. It can only be set in php.ini http://php.net/manual/en/curl.configuration.php

Comment: @Machavity, may i know what can i do for this? since it's only system wide php.ini file which is not accessible

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom PHP runtime, and then you can change `php.ini` and any of the `PHP_INI_SYSTEM` configurations.

[Check here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-configure/) for details on how to use a custom php runtime, but basically you will upload the php version as a part of your site, and set is as the handler for `*.php` in Portal.

Comment: why using entirely custom PHP runtime, while the link to documentation you provide also explains how to simply add configure the pre-built PHP runtime with adding .user.ini file and change configuration?

Comment: because not all of php settings can be set in .user.ini. http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php this outlines the different settings modes. And [curl.cainfo](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.configuration.php) is `PHP_INI_SYSTEM` setting only, meaning it has to be in the system level php.ini